# FFMPEG BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, ffmpeg, moviepy

I have a multiprocess pool calling different instances of ffmpeg and outputing a video file. Some of these videos are hundreds of megabytes and take a while to create. I'm seemingly getting IO bottlenecked:

```
  File "<decorator-gen-54>", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 135, in use_clip_fps_by_default
    return f(clip, *new_a, **new_kw)
  File "<decorator-gen-53>", line 2, in write_videofile
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moviepy/decorators.py", line 22, in convert_masks_to_RGB
    return f(clip, *a, **k)
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moviepy/video/VideoClip.py", line 307, in write_videofile
    logger=logger)
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_writer.py", line 216, in ffmpeg_write_video
    ffmpeg_params=ffmpeg_params) as writer:
  File "/home/xxx/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/moviepy/video/io/ffmpeg_writer.py", line 129, in __init__
    self.proc = sp.Popen(cmd, **popen_params)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 800, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1482, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
BlockingIOError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
"""
```

This is weird but iotop never shows me with more than 10% io. My CPU is doing fine too, I have plenty of idle cores when this is running.

The error here shows that its happening on ffmpeg_write, so clearly an IO constraint.

Is there a way to make the write call threaded(I assume that's the fix)? Is that ok even though this is happening in a multiprocess pool?